# creating a blackjack game using javascript, html and css only

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile-application, blackjack

I am coding a mobile app using PhoneGap, and I am only using HTML and JavaScript. so far, i have made all of the betting functions, such as starting an initial bet, buttons to increase or decrease the bet, and the functions that are called when the player wins, loses, or gets blackjack. My problem is with the deck.

It might be helpful to know what I called my functions, I don't know, but here they are anyway:

- `function win()` adds the value in the bet to the total money.
- `function lose()` subtracts the value that was bet from the total money.
- `function blackjack()` adds one and a half times the value bet to the total money, and I used the `Math.floor()` on that one.

So with that in mind, I have two questions.

1. I want to have a deck that is just like a physical deck. I might be a little picky, but i want it so that if a card is shown, it will not be called again until all 52 cards are used, or the deck is shuffled. The cards can come out at random, i don't care as long as the cards are not repeated. also, how would you separate the piles that are dealt?

   For example, one pile is the user, the other is the dealer. i kinda think this is needed because we will use the card values to add and decide who has won.

   This next part is not required, but would be nice.

   Would there be a way that I could add an image to the card that is chosen, so that the player can visually see the card that is drawn?
2. Using JavaScript, html and css `__ONLY__`, could I save a value to the apps internal memory or something?  What I'm trying to achieve is that when, the player closes the app, the amount of money that is their "winnings" will be saved, and shown the next time they open the app.

I also have one more question, but this one is not part of the app.

Do anyone know how old you have to be to sign up for a Google developer account? I want to publish my app when I finish, but I'm only 17 and I don't know if I'm allowed to create a Google developer account to post my app on Google play because of my age.

Answer (score 0):

To store some data in the client side, you can use the localStorage in a web browser, maybe it is not the best method to work in Android, but ut works.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

localStorage.getItem("key");
```

there you can store info

Comment: would I put this in the html or the script? and if it's the script, do I include this in a function or variable?

Comment: @firebend77 well as localstorage is a veriable in javascript, put it in the part of script.... in any case, google can ask the questions sometimes faster than us, so search quite a little before asking, [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) as you can see this is the first result when you search localstorage in google if you are in javascript and don't find a variable in your program, just put a debugger and searh for it

Comment: thanks for trying, but it didn't work. I'm sure it's just either the puritan I'm using won't allow it, or it doesn't work with android.